# Где хранить токен в мобильном приложении?

Tags: android, vue.js, mobile-development, cordova

У меня есть проект на vue, который через cordova я создаю apk.
Хочу понять есть ли у мобильных приложений local sorage?и если есть , стирается он при закрытии приложения?
Я хочу реализовать сессию и думаю где хранить токен, который я буду отправлять.

Answer (score 3):

В качестве `local storage` в Android используется `SharedPreferences`. Они работают, скрывая за абстракцией с методами типа `String getString(String key)` и `void putString(String key, String value)` работу с обычным xml файлом. Этот файл хранится в папке приложения и удаляется в 2 случаях - приложение удалено (на самом деле в этом случае не всегда удаляется и может быть восстановлено, но это отдельный вопрос) и данные приложения очищены.